# How to prevent advanced relation field setting «Relate entries from a specific site?» getting ignored?

Tags: relations, field, multi-site, bug

I have a relation field with the advanced setting «Relate entries from a specific site?».
When the user initially clicks on the field it works fine, on a second attempt the setting «Relate entries from a specific site?» get's ignored and shows the entries from the same site.
Is this a bug? How can I prevent this? (Version 4.4.16.1)